# Load pkl file (comes from python2) into python 3, using sklearn

Tags: python

Loading the pkl file generated from python 2 into python3 module , is it possible to load?

I tried by encoding with the 'bytes' giving

> `sklearn.grid_search error.Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/analysis/run.py", line 227, in run_predictions gs_model = gs_lib.load_model_from_pkl(r'model.pkl') File "/home/analysis/gs_lib.py", line 326, in load_model_from_pkl gs_model = pickle.load(f,encoding='latin1') ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.grid_search'`

```
def loadpkl(filename=None):
    if filename is None:
        filename = 'old.pkl'
        f = open(filename, 'rb')
        model = pickle.load(f,encoding='latin1')
        data = pickle.load(model,encoding='bytes')
        return model
```

Comment: it depends. did you try?

Comment: Should work going to a later release.

Comment: look at this article this might help you , https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/convert-py2-pickles-to-py3/

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add codes and error messages to the post. As you can see, the indentation and the readability gets lost in the comments.